# How to append stacked character values

Tags: java, stack

I need help with appending the pushed elements in a stack. I want the returnItems method below to return the pushed elements onto the stack which will be used to comapare to the string below if it's a palindrome.

Each character of this string is pushed on to the stack: abcdef

Here's the returnItems method. How do I modify the bolded part in order to get the return value (for example: fedcba from the example above):

```
public T returnItems() {
    Node<T> temp = top;
    T value = null;

    if (top == null) { // checks if stack is empty
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        value = null;
    }

    System.out.println("Elements: ");
    while (temp.getInfo() != null) {
        value = temp.getInfo(); // get the current character

        // How do I append the characters that the value variable temporarily holds
        // for each loop
        ***value = (T) (value + " "  + temp.getLink());*** // append it to the current character

        if (temp.getLink() == null) { // if the next link is null, the loop will break
            break;
        }

        temp = temp.getLink(); // else, get the next link
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the Java [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class?

Comment: We are required to implement it on our own for our subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use T for both elements on the stack (could have been `Character` for `char`), and result, `String`, it must be assumed you have a `Stack<String>` or so, and thus a `Node<String>`.

```
public String returnItems() {    
    String reversed = ""; // Better a StringBuilder.
    while (top != null) {
        String ch = top.getInfo(); // get the current character
        reversed = reversed + ch;
        top = top.getLink(); // or `pop()` or such.
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

So: use a concrete type, not T. This means that `returnItems` must *not* be in the Stack class itself, as palindromes are for character stacks (a Stack usage) only. And I would have expected to see:

```
class Stack<T> {
    T top() { ... }
    boolean isEmpty() { ... }
    T pop() { ... }
    void push(T item) { ... }
}

Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<>();

public String returnItems() {    
    String reversed = ""; // Better a StringBuilder.
    while (!charStack.isEmpty()) {
        char ch = charStack.pop(); // get the current character
        reversed += ch;
    }
    return reversed;
}
```